# How to display in my webpage picture saved in Mysql as Medium Blob?

Tags: php, mysql, html, image, blob

So i have this code in the HTML:

```
 <img src="imagescript.php?id=1">
```

And i have this code in the imagescript.php :

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $conn= mysql_connect($servername,$username)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("licitatii",$conn);
    $sql="select picture from auctions where auction_id='$_GET[id]'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $image = $row['picture'];
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    print $image;
 ?>
```

I have used this from instructions on the internet but my image doesn't display .

Is it possible that I have incorrectly uploaded the image?

I used   < input name="regphoto" type="file" >  in a method="POST" form and then inserted in the table the $_POST[regphoto]

If it helps you, here's the php script i used to insert the photo after clicking the submit button:

$sql="insert into auctions (`auction_id`,`owner_id`,`parent_category_id`,`title`,`description`,`picture`,`postage`,`starting_price`,`buyout_price`,`end_date`)values(NULL,'$ownerid','$parentcategoryid','$_POST[regtitle]','$_POST[regdescription]','$_POST[regphoto]','$_POST[regpostage]','$_POST[regstartingprice]','$_POST[regbuyoutprice]','$expiration')";

As u can see, I inserted into the "picture" column(type mediumblob) the value $_POST[regphoto]

Comment: What code are you referring to?

Comment: @AllisonC sorry i didn't know i had to indent spaces to see the code

Comment: If you do a var_dump($image) before the header, do you get any data?

Comment: @AllisonC Unfortunately no :(

Comment: echo $sql and paste it directly in the db and see if you get results or if you get an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments that might help:

1. You probably need to login to the mysql server with a password (although not necessarily...).
2. You need to protect your code from sql injection attacks, the easiest way in your case would be something like `$id = (int) $_GET[id]` and use `$id` in your query.
3. You will have to post the php code you used to insert the image as well, as inserting `$_POST[photo]` sounds wrong: You need `$_FILES['photo']` and that is an array, see the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: ok thanks for the extra info but the main issue for now is to be able to display the images. This is a part of my final project for college and security issues are not a priority right now

Comment: @user783476 You´re not going to have much images to show if someone can wipe out your whole database by just entering a url ;-) Anyway, check points 1. and 3.

Comment: what do you mean $_POST['photo'] is an array? It is of the type "file" as it says in the input tag

Comment: if you know and have the time, can you post step by step instructions on how to properly insert a picture in my database? In the case i am mistaken. The tutorials on the net are confusing for me

Comment: @user783476 Sorry, my third point was not completely correct, I´ve changed it now. I don't have any code to upload images to a db as I never do that; I just save the file somewhere on the server and store some of it´s properties in a db, not the contents.